# How to achieve the top-down (oblique) projection of textures using an OrthographicCamera?

Tags: libgdx, camera, projection-matrix

This question is related to ([How to calculate the initial velocity of projectile motion by a given distance and angle from point A to B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692488/how-to-calculate-initial-velocity-of-projectile-motion-by-a-given-distance-and-a)) question.

**Details**

In the below image is the graphical projection of top-down (oblique).

[image]

And this is the pattern that I used to reference.

[image]

**Currently**

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757336/2801777), the Coordinate systems describes how the oblique projection works.

```
screenPos.x = (worldPos.x - cameraOffset.x) * zoomFactor;
screenPos.y = (worldPos.y + worldPos.z - cameraOffset.y) * zoomFactor;
```

From the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692488/how-to-calculate-initial-velocity-of-projectile-motion-by-a-given-distance-and-a), currently the camera that I'm using is [`OrthographicCamera`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html).

**Additional question**

In the above GIF animation, do I need to customize `OrthographicCamera` class to achieve the oblique projection? Or do I need to create a new `ObliqueCamera` class that extends `Camera`? (If yes, what pointers do I need to review to be able to do it, because I am new to graphical projection).